# HTML+CSS : how to move not close divs to create a right column?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

I have a problem that I thought was pretty simple but that is taking me a lot of time to solve it. If there is a simple solution (and I don't know CSS enough), please point me there and I'll close this question immediately.

My problem is the following.

I have 6 divs one on top of another, something like:

```
<div id="header">header content</div>
<div id="sidebar1">sidebar1 content</div>
<div id="maincontent">maincontent content</div>
<div id="maincontent2">maincontent2 content</div>
<div id="sidebar2">sidebar2 content</div>
<div id="footer">footer content</div>
```

What I want to have is something like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| header content                                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------  -------------------
| maincontent content                |  | sidebar1 content|
|                                    |  -------------------
|                                    |  -------------------
|                                    |  | sidebar2 content|
|                                    |  -------------------
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
| maincontent2content                |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------
| footer content                                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

In other words, is there a way to create a right column even if the divs are not one after another using only CSS and without moving the divs in the code?

I tried to use for sidebar1 the following css

```
 position:absolute;
 top:3em;
 right:0;
```

and for sidebar2 the following css

```
 position:absolute;
 top:9.5em;
 right:0;
```

but I have the impression that this is not the right way to do it.

A simple way could be to define the `top` attribute size as a function of the height of heather, but I couldn't find any way to do it only with CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: You could take a look at [960.gs](http://960.gs). It's great for column layouts, and nice if you're not too sure on your CSS (and a great way to learn).

Comment: I would like to use a stylesheet created by me and not external tools... it's more an exercise than a real implementation...

Comment: There's no shame in looking at other people's work to see how they do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... as a direct answer to your question, you can use a combination of floats and % widths to accomplish this.  You can also use fixed widths, but you'll have to determine what those sizes are.  Here's a simple implementation:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qDHkr/)

---

### CSS

```
#maincontent
{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    background:#ee5;
}

#sidebar2,#sidebar1
{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    background:#5e5;
}

#footer
{
    clear:both;
    background:#5ee;
}

#header
{
    background:#55e;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="header">header content</div>
<div id="sidebar1" class="side">sidebar1 content</div>
<div id="maincontent">maincontent content</div>
<div id="sidebar2" class="side">sidebar2 content</div>
<div id="footer">footer content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code: I checked and it works, but my problem was caused by a second "content" div before the "sidebar2". In this case the sidebar2 is aligned to the second content and doesn't go just under the sidebar 1!

Comment: Ok, I solved putting the content in an unique container, so I can apply your code, but is there a way without putting the 2 "maincontent" in an unique container?

Comment: @GiovanniDiMilia Yes there is, :)  You can use the same rule for the other content (float left at 70% or so width).  See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qDHkr/4/